# how to return two values in one function without using struct?

Tags: c

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>


        double calculate(int ar[], int npts, int *gtr);


        int main()
        {

            int ar[4] = {1,2,3,0};
            double result;
            result = calculate(ar,4, &ar);
            printf("%lf ",result );         


            return 0;
        }


        double calculate(int ar[], int npts, int *gtr)
        {
            double total =0;
            int i = 0;

            double average;

            for(i=0; i<npts; i++)
            {
                total = total + ar[i];
            }

            average = total / npts;
            return average;

            for(i=0; i<npts; i++)
            {
                if(average < ar[i])
                {
                    *gtr++; 
                }
            }     

            return *gtr;
        }
```

when i call function calculate i want to return both average and *gtr value
but avergage only average value return. *gtr is for counting how many numbers greater than average numbers in arrary.

Comment: What `struct` are you talking about? There isn't any as of now in the code you have posted.

Comment: Aren't you getting warnings?

Comment: You can pass a variable by reference.

Comment: @stuartd it's hard to return two values using `union`, though.

Comment: http://ideone.com/WrB2PG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what i understand,you want to return the average,and somehow get the value of gtr.you can return the average value,and save the gtr value to another variable by using a pointer.

```
int main()
{

    int ar[4] = {1,2,3,0};
    double result;
    int gtr = 0;
    result = calculate(ar,4,&gtr);
    printf("%lf\n",result );
    printf("gtr : %d\n",gtr);


    return 0;
}


double calculate(int ar[], int npts, int *gtr)
{
    double total = 0 , average;

    int i = 0;

    for(i=0; i<npts; i++)
    {
        total = total + ar[i];
    }

    average = total / npts;

    for( i = 0 ; i < npts ; i++ )
    {
         if(average < ar[i])
                 {
                      *gtr += 1; 
                  }
           }
    return average;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You made the function almost right, it's the call that must be done differently.

First, don't return `*gtr` from the function; return `average`. Do it at the end, though, not in the middle.

Then, change the call to

```
int gtr;
result = calculate(ar,4, &gtr);
printf("%lf %d\n",result, gtr);
```

Make sure that you set `*gtr` to zero before the second loop, otherwise it would remain uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

For return both value you can do this:

```
    double calculate(int ar[], int npts, int *gtr)
    {
        double total =0;
        int i = 0;

        double average;

        for(i=0; i<npts; i++)
        {
            total = total + ar[i];
        }

        average = total / npts;
        return average;

        for(i=0; i<npts; i++)
        {
            if(average < ar[i])
            {
                *gtr++; 
            }
        }     

        return avergage;
    }
```

so, returning avergage you have the first variable, and using the puntator value of gtr you can have that value.